# How can I use javascript to check if a sharepoint textfield contains a specific word, when the textbox text changes or get added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a weird sharepoint textfield that look like this:

```
<div class="ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor-standard ms-taxonomy-writing" title="Category" style="width: 364px;">


<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanel5Medium_NewsCategoryMedium_ctl02editableRegion" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion ms-inputBox ms-inputBoxActive" disableribboncommands="True" allowmultilines="false" restrictpastetotext="True" rtedirty="false" style="">
<span class="valid-text" title="">Communications</span>;&nbsp;&#8203;
<span id="ms-rterangecursor-start"></span>
<span id="ms-rterangecursor-end">
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

In the ASPX file it looks like this:

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModePanel5Medium" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Edit">
     <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl  FieldName="NewsCategory" runat="server" id="NewsCategoryMedium" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Since the text that get inserted in to the textbox gets appended to `.Valid-text` element, no idea why lol.. I would like to check if textbox get changed/focused and then check the `.valid-text` if it contains lets say "hello world".

I have tried this so far but with no luck.

```
    $(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor").change(function () {
        var Text = $(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor .valid-text").text();

        if (Text == "Hello World") {
            // do this
        }


    });
```

Also tried Tyme's solution but no luck there also :(

```
    $(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor").blur(function () {
        var text = $(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor .valid-text").text();
        if (text.indexOf('Group Wide') != -1) {
            alert("test");
        }


    });
```

Also tried

```
    $(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor").on("blur", function () {
        var text = $(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor .valid-text").text();
        alert(text);
        if (text.indexOf('Group Wide') != -1) {
            alert("test");
            $("#news-text").show();
        }
    });
```

here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wdjvy/

any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.change()` wont fire on content editable div's, try using `blur()`

```
$(".ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor").blur(function () {
    var Text = $(this).text();

    if (Text == "Hello World") {
        // do this
    }


});
```

You can also reference ASP.NET controls via ID (if your JS is in the same file) by using this format:

```
$("#<%= EditModePanel5Medium.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: Alright ill try that out but am I picking the right selectors?

Comment: If your JS is in the same file, reference the ID. If it's not, add a unique class and reference that class.

Comment: Its not working :( What do you mean with add unique class, I cant add a class to a taxonomyfieldcontrol just cssClass

Answer (score -2):

Use following:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor[title="YourFieldTitle"]').text();
}
```